# How to pre-select an option in two chained, populated with JSON dropdown lists, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have two classic chained country and city dropdown lists. They're populated with JSON, but I faced 2 issues. The first one is: How to make the default, selected option to be "Select a country", respectively "Select a city" without getting an error.

The second one is: How to make a certain option pre-selected **after** the dropdown populates with JSON?

P.S. If someone has a solution in pure JavaScript I will also be happy.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
  let countriesCitiesURL = "https://api.npoint.io/0114d901f1e3dbd47abe";
  
  $.getJSON(countriesCitiesURL, (selectData) => {        
        function updateSelects(event) {
            let cities = selectData[this.value].map((key, val) => {
                return $("<option />").text(key).val(key);
            });            
            $(event.data.target).empty().append(cities); 
        }
        let stateBirth;
        
        for (stateBirth in selectData) {        
            $('#country').append(`<option value="${stateBirth}">${stateBirth}</option>`);
        }
        
        $("#country").on("change", {target: "#city"}, updateSelects);
    
    /* This one is working */
    // if (4 > 3) {
    //  $("#country").val(selectedCountry);
    // }
        
        
    }).fail( () => { alert("Error!"); });
    
    let selectedCountry = "GERMANY";
    
    /* But I need to make this one work... */
    // if (4 > 3) {
        // $("#country").val(selectedCountry);
    // }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option>Please select a country</option>
</select>

<select id="city">
  <option>Please select a city</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, question 1 is, how to make the dropdown display “Select a country” and “Select a city” by default, before the user select any value. Question 2 is, how to pre-select a city after the user select a country. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: If I select England, what should be the pre-select city?

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski yes you understand correctly! And if you select England, it still has to show "Select a city" until the user chooses one of the cities of England.

Comment: On question 2, to make option pre-select, first you need to define your data which option to be select first, and that required a change on your json format. Because currently, no information regarding pre-selection is presented.

Answer (score 0):

1. An error is thrown when you select “Select a country” because the city dropdown cannot find the corresponding cities to display. There is no country named “Select a country”. To fix that you need to check if a valid country option is selected. You can do that by check the value of the country select.
2. To render the dropdown with pre-selected option, first you need to tell which option you want to be pre-selected. The sample data has no information regarding pre-selection. We need to add that.

I modify the API response as follow. The Boolean indicate pre-select option. True is pre-selected of course. In this example, MANCHESTER is the default for ENGLAND. HAMBURG is the default for GERMANY.

```
{
  "ENGLAND": {
    "LONDON": false,
    "MANCHESTER": true,
    "LIVERPOOL": false
  },
  "GERMANY": {
    "MUNICH": false,
    "BERLIN": false,
    "HAMBURG": true
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let countriesCitiesURL = "https://api.npoint.io/9de0952973958c474e90";

  $.getJSON(countriesCitiesURL, (selectData) => {
    function updateSelects(event) {
      let cityOptions;

      if (this.value) {
        // valid country is selected
        let cities = selectData[this.value];
        cityOptions = Object.keys(cities).map(function(key) {
          var opt = $("<option />").text(key).val(key);

          // pre-selection check
          if (this[key]) {
            // if true, render it as selected
            opt = opt.attr('selected', '');
          }
          return opt;
        }, cities);
      } else {
        // the placeholder is selected
        cityOptions = $('<option />').text('Please select a city');
      }

      $(event.data.target).empty().append(cityOptions);
    }
    let stateBirth;

    for (stateBirth in selectData) {
      $('#country').append(`<option value="${stateBirth}">${stateBirth}</option>`);
    }

    $("#country").on("change", {
      target: "#city"
    }, updateSelects);

    /* This one is working */
    // if (4 > 3) {
    //  $("#country").val(selectedCountry);
    // }


  }).fail(() => {
    alert("Error!");
  });

  let selectedCountry = "GERMANY";

  /* But I need to make this one work... */
  // if (4 > 3) {
  // $("#country").val(selectedCountry);
  // }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option value="">Please select a country</option>
</select>

<select id="city">
  <option>Please select a city</option>
</select>
```